# Can you reuse product identifiers for in app purchase on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When you pick a `product identifier` in iTunes Connect does it have to be unique throughout the app store, or just within your app?  And if you delete a product with a given product identifier, can you then reuse it for a different product? I've been doing some testing in iTunes Connect but I don't want to sabotage the most logical ProductID's during my testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've discovered, once you delete a product with a given `product identifier`, iTunes Connect **does not** let you reuse that ID again.  However, I've found a workaround.  The product identifiers are case-sensitive, so if you just change your capitalization when you reuse the product id, iTunes Connect won't stop you. (However, as *il Malvagio Dottor Prosciutto* states, that could be risky).

Also, with brief testing, it doesn't appear that your product identifiers have to be unique throughout the store.  I tried some pretty common words that I thought others might have used for product ID's and they all worked.

Note that the products I did my testing on were various durations of a recurring subscription in the app store.  I don't know if the rules differ for other types of products.

Comment: Can seams obvious, but pay attention to non-case sensitive IDs: Apple may change it in a future release without notice... ;)

Comment: I confirm this answer (I had the same problem). After testing, product identifiers have to be unique by account. At the time of writing, you can't reuse the same product identifier in another app from the same iTunes account. But you can reuse the product identifier of another app from another iTunes Connect account.